# What does the T stand for in R time format?

Tags: r

I was going through this script and found the author used

```
time.start <- as.POSIXct("2009-07-1 00:00:00T")
```

I'm confused of what the T in time stand for.

Comment: I would guess it stands for **T**ypo

Comment: That's not an R thing, it's just a way that some people format their time stamps. More commonly you will see the `T` separating the date and time, e.g. `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS`.

Comment: `as.POSIXct` seems to ignore stuff after the time, at least on my platform (Ubuntu 12.04); `as.POSIXct("2009-07-1 00:00:00garbage")==as.POSIXct("2009-07-1 00:00:00")` is `TRUE`

Comment: @BenBolker From `?as.POSIXct`: "Character input is first converted to class "`POSIXlt`" by `strptime`". Then from `?strptime`: "Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letters at the end of the timestamp usually indicate the time zone.
"2015-11-15 18:31:51 GMT"
"2015-11-15 10:32:11 PST"

The only single letter timezone abbreviation seems to be "Z". 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations

It is possible you have a typo where the space and first two letters of the timezone were deleted.